# Save into Database by Repository SpringBoot MVC

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have to store "extractedNumbers" into SQL Database but I can't manage it. I have  created ExtractedNumbersRepository interface but I can't access it from this method and I don't know how to do it. Could somebody help me please?

```
public class Lotto6From49 extends Thread {
```

// Save lucky numbers in Database
public  ExtractedNumbers addExNr() {

```
    ExtractedNumbers extractedNumbers = new ExtractedNumbers();
    extractedNumbers.setExtractedNumbers(luckyNumbers.toString());
    extractedNumbers.setExtractionDate(timeNow);
   
    return extractedNumbers;

}
```

}

```
@Repository
```

public interface ExtractedNumbersRepository extends JpaRepository<ExtractedNumbers,Integer> {

}

Answer (score 0):

You should implement a service and inject the **ExtractedNumbersRepository** dependency:

```
@Service
public class ExtractedNumbersServiceImpl {
@Autowired
ExtractedNumbersRepository theExtractedNumbersRepository;


public void saveextractedNumbers(ExtractedNumbers extractedNumbers){
 //here you can call the repository and save the extracted numbers
 this.theExtractedNumbersRepository.save(extractedNumbers);
 }
}
```

The next step is to inject the Service dependency inside your Lotto6From49 or controller:

```
private final ExtractedNumbersServiceImpl theExtractedNumbersServiceImpl;

public Lotto6From49(ExtractedNumbersServiceImpl extractedNumbersServiceImpl) {
    this.theExtractedNumbersServiceImpl= extractedNumbersServiceImpl;
}
```

Now you can call:

```
theExtractedNumbersServiceImpl.saveextractedNumbers(extractedNumbers);
```